# Android webview login

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to build an android application for my web site.

The web site consists of the web server and a mysql database and has a user login system. I wanted to avoid messing with php and json to build the authentication system in my app so I thought I could use a webview instead. I'm thinking something like the facebook login where a pop up window opens and you login to your facebook account and then return to the application. Is that possible and if so can you tell me how?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is Oauth2 there are lots of libraries you can use to help you do this here is one by google https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v1 they also have authUtil if you want to use googleLogins. Otherwise a search for android oauth2 will give you plenty of tutorials and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Then its kind of an API i would say? Maybe this helps:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

At the beginning, he's creating an API as well, it could give you some inspirations. Hope it helps a bit :)